# My destructor is called every tick

Tags: c++, sdl, destructor

False alarm! (read the edit)

I'm trying to make a small game, using SDL. When an entity is created, its image should up the refcount, and that's no problem. The problem comes when it's time to use "SDL_FreeSurface(image)" (do decrease it), this should happen within the entity itself so I'm trying to create my own destructor, as a test to see if it got called at all I added a cout, but it's called every tick for some reason? It's not deleting anything so I suppose I also have to take care of all the entities values when I do get it to work (thought that I only had to take care of the special cases, such as this).

```
Entity::~Entity()
{
    cout << "I'm deleted" << endl;
    //SDL_FreeSurface(image);
}
```

If destructors are supposed to be called all the time (?) why is that?

EDIT
I just realized that during each tick I use some temporary entities, it's probably those that get deconstructed, sorry feel free to lock this.

Comment: Destructors are not supposed to be called every tick, this is pretty weird. Can you add some of the update code you're using ? No one will figure out how the destructor is called every tick without some code.

Comment: No, destructors called at object deletion. We need the code where you use the `Entity` object. You might be passing it somewhere as value instead of reference that creates a copy of your object, and the copy is destructed.

Comment: Destructors are only called once: when an object is destroyed. This leads to the conclusion that you create and destroy Entity objects every tick. You probably just don't notice. When you're passing Entity objects to a different function, there's often a copy of it being made which will be destroyed once the function ends. But to exactly see what's going on we'd need to see more of your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your destructor will be called every time an object of class Entity is destroyed and only then.

If your destructor is called at every tick, that means an object is destroyed at every tick. Likely you're creating a temporary Entity object at every tick and it gets destroyed right away (for example you might be passing an Entity object by value).

Comment: That is exactly what I'm doing, I realized that shortly after I posted this, during the editing of the post alot have answered :) thanks!